# Differential Drive ROS Plugin stops responding after reset_simulation or reset_world

Tags: gazebo, plugin, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a cross-post with one at answers.gazebosim.org, but it's not getting much traffic over there so I thought I would try here as well.

I have a basic differential drive robot that uses the differential drive ROS plugin that stops responding after I call `reset_simulation` or `reset_world`. I'm using ROS Hydro and Gazebo 1.9. For context, I am trying to collect data on several sets of trajectories (100's of trajectories total), which is why I would like to be able to reset the simulator and drive the next trajectory automatically.

As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with any code I have written. When I start up Gazebo and the model loads in an empty world, the model will respond to commands sent on `/cmd_vel`, even using `rostopic pub`, so I know it's not any problem with code I have written. After using `rosservice call /gazebo/reset_simulation` or `reset_world`, the position of the model is reset correctly and the simulation continues to run, but commands sent to `/cmd_vel` are ignored.

One hint that might be helpful, is that if I call reset_simulation, the `/odom` topic is no longer published to either, but if I call reset_world, the `/odom` topic continues to be published (and it indicates a tiny amount of movement in the model).

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or some sort of problem with the way I am specifying my model (it's a pretty simple model, so that seems unlikely), but I have replicated it on two different computers.

Has anyone else run into this issue? If so, how did you resolve it? If it is in fact a bug, where should I submit the bug report?

Thanks in advance for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114931/differential-drive-ros-plugin-stops-responding-after-reset_simulation-or-reset_world/) by [Matt_Derry](https://answers.ros.org/users/3061/matt_derry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-01-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's now a pull request for this issue. https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pull/298

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0